# SSRS: How to find reports for a given user?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've got a couple of different user accounts set up in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005, and I'd like to programatically check (via their web services) which reports a given user has access to.
How to I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ReportingService2005 web service's ListChildren web method. It will return a list of CatalogItems that the current user can access. Then remove items that aren't Reports.

```
List<CatalogItem> result = new List<CatalogItem>();
result.AddRange(ListChildren(SOME_PATH_BLAH_BLAH_BLAH, true));
result.RemoveAll(delegate(CatalogItem item)
                                {
                                    return item.Type != ItemTypeEnum.Report;
                                });
```

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.listchildren.aspx -

> The ListChildren method returns only child items that the user has permission to view. The items that are returned may not represent a complete list of child items of the specified parent item.

Comment: Are you aware of what base permissions/roles the user requires to access the web services? When calling with users with basic report permissions, I get an error stating `the permissions granted are insufficient for performing this operation.`